# Why table variable SQL doesn't return values in R Markdown?

Tags: sql, r, r-markdown, markdown

Can't understand why R Markdown doesn't return values for table variable SQL? I use notebook in R Studio.

For example:

```sql
declare @CountriesTable as TABLE (countries varchar(2))
        insert into @CountriesTable values ('us'), ('gb'), ('de'), ('fr')
 
 select * from @CountriesTable
```

in MSSMS returns

[image]

In R Markdown I get 0 Rows:

[image]

Comment: I haven't tested it, but do you need a `;` after your `insert into` line?

Comment: @r2evans I've tried `;` for both lines after `declare` and `insert into`, it doesn't work...

Comment: As revealed through research for questions of other people DBI package does not seem to work with T-SQL INSERT INTO non-numeric data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your statement *"does not work with non-numeric data"* is quite wrong, `DBI` (with SQL Server) supports SQL Server's `bit`, `integer`, `float` variants, `datetimeoffset` variants, `char`/`varchar`/`nchar`/`nvarchar` variants, etc.
2. Suggested [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/127), add `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Demonstration:

````
---
title: Why table variable SQL doesn't return values in R Markdown?
---

```{r setup}
library(DBI)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), ...) # redacted
```

```{sql connection=con}
set nocount on
declare @CountriesTable as TABLE (countries varchar(2))
insert into @CountriesTable values ('us'), ('gb'), ('de'), ('fr')
select * from @CountriesTable
```
````

[image: rendered rmarkdown]

Ultimately, I believe the issue is that `DBI` does not deal with with multiple result-sets. While I had expected that `odbc`'s [PR 345](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/pull/345) would have addressed this in odbc-1.3.0, it does not seem to deal correctly with the first resultset (`4`, number of rows inserted) and the second (four rows of data).